# How to add negative float in NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

Ok. i don't see ways to done it. But maybe some one knows?
I don't need use NSString to put it in array, because it makes huge memory usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *array = @[@(-16.f)].mutableCopy;
for (NSNumber *number in array) {
    NSLog(@"%f", number.floatValue);
}
```

Comment: how about NSMutableArray?

Comment: `NSMutableArray *array = @[@(-16.f), @(-30.f)].mutableCopy;` will also work.

Comment: Ok.Thanks but how i can add it in mutable array? addObject method not allow use floats and negative values.

Comment: `[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:-1.f]];` or `[array addObject:@(-1.f)];`

Comment: Just use `@-16`  no need for the parentheses.

Comment: Don't use dot syntax for non-properties.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to convert your`float` value to`NSNumber` using @(floatValue) .

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; // here you can add value using initWithObject method.

[arr addObject:@(-16)]; // here you can add your float value using @(float value).

NSLog(@" array = %@",arr);
```

When you retrive value from array .

```
float yourValue = [[arr objectAtIndex:(your index)] floatValue];
```

hope it help you .